# Implement UISearchController with UITableView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

Just wondering about the code that was used for the [Raywenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift) on how to add a `UISearchController` and how to use it with a `UITableViewController` I can't seem to get it working and someone told me that it may have got deprecated in iOS 8.0, does anyone know on how to still do this?

The `UISearchController` was Built In The `UIViewController` NOT StoryBoard!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UISearchDisplayController` has been deprecated and replaced by `UISearchController`.And it is available in **iOS 8.0** and later.

> The UISearchController class defines an interface that manages the
>   presentation of a search bar in concert with the search results
>   controller’s content. The search results controller, a
>   UIViewController object specified by the searchResultsController
>   property, manages the results of the search

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html

Here is an example ,how i do it with `UITableView` resding in `UIViewController`..Just make few changes if you want to use with `UITableViewController`...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {


    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var tabledata = ["lucques","chickendijon","godaddy","amazon","chris","ambata","bankofamerica","abelcine","AUTO + TRANSPORTATION","BILLS + UTILITIES","FOOD + DINING","HEALTH","AutoCare", "Auto Payment" , "Gas+Fuel","Electric Bill", "Internet/Television","Fast Foodd", "Gorceries" , "Restaurants","Gym Membership", "Health Insurance","auto","note-bullet","knife","heart"]

    var filteredTableData = [String]()

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self

        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.tblView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar


            return controller


        })()
        self.tblView.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }



     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if self.resultSearchController.active {


           return self.filteredTableData.count

        }else{


            return self.tabledata.count



        }

    }



     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var section = indexPath.section
        var row = indexPath.row
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"addCategoryCell")
        cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)

        if self.resultSearchController.active {

              cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]


        }else{

                 cell.textLabel?.text = tabledata[indexPath.row]

        }

        return cell

    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

        let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]

        self.tblView.reloadData()



    }



}
```

Comment: Also is there a way to add it so when the UISearchController is displayed the cells are still shown because at the moment the cells are not being shown untill you enter the name you want to search for, otherwise thanks! :D @anishparajuli