# UISearchController doesn't want to appear because he is not in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to make search in my UITableViewController using UISearchController. For starter project i use [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).
I made some changes and I want to use one class instead of thee as in example. I am adding my UISearchController from code. My problem is I cannot call UISearchController because of exeption :

```
2015-06-18 13:35:04.750 TableSearch[4796:77813] Warning: Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x7fe09b719f00> on <APLMainTableViewController: 0x7fe09b50e450> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

[Working project with changes](https://github.com/Yurssoft/IOSVC/tree/master/TableSearch)

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: here is an full example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851467/implement-uisearchcontroller-with-uitableview/30851918?noredirect=1#comment49749974_30851918

Comment: The solution was to set nil in initWithSearchResultsController! Yes your answer helped to understand the problem, thanks.

Comment: great................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that I wanted to run UISearchController :

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self];
```

Solution is to initialise UISearchController :

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
```

and leave storyboard as it was.

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer:

```
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
```

For those wanting a working example with search results, see my repo https://github.com/Optimbyte/IOSVC-master

Old answer:
I think you forgot to add in MainStoryBoard a search bar and search display controller. [image: required]

Comment: may be UISearchDisplayController is not what he wants?

Comment: The solution was to set nil in initWithSearchResultsController! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated answer with link to github to also fix search result issue: table not reloading.