# Get informations on Search bar in Swift

Tags: string, swift, searchbar

I have this code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reload()
}

private func reload() {
    let requestUrl = "https://www.themoviedb.org/search/remote/multi?query=(XXXXXX)&language=en"
```

The user will write the (XXXXXX) in search bar.

How Can I catch this from search bar and transform into a string ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851467/implement-uisearchcontroller-with-uitableview/30851918#30851918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From the xib/storyboard, get the reference of the searchbar by creating an IBOutlet like so

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar:UISearchBar!
   ```
2. You can implement various delegate methods to observe the changes in the text and/or simply do `searchBar.text` to access the text entered b the user.